# New internal hard drive and Ubuntu OS

Tags: hard-drive

I have a very crappy Acer Aspire and I can to switch out the internal hard drive for a better one. What's the easiest way to get Ubuntu on the new drive if it doesn't have an OS at all and the Acer came with no reboot CDs?

Answer (score 1):

- [Make an Ubuntu LiveCD/USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- Shut down the machine, remove the old drive, install the new drive
- insert the CD/USB
- boot the machine from CD/USB
- [install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Easy-peasy, even easier than replacing an existing OS. What are "reboot CDs", by the way?

Comment: Reboot CD=Recovery CD aka System restore discs.

Comment: Well, the OP does not need any "Reboot CDs" then, they contain Windows anyway.